# I forgot my ubuntu autheticate password!

Tags: password-recovery

I was  trying to download GIMP on my computer,it asked for a autheticate password!
of course I didn't know it,so I wasn't going to try to type it in if it was only going to say it was wrong
What should I do?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system and select Advanced options from Grub. Then select *Ubuntu (recovery mode)* and change password for existing user:

1. Run

   ```
   passwd user_name
   ```

   Replace `user_name` with your actual username.
2. Type password when prompt:

   ```
   Enter new UNIX password:
   ```
3. Retype password (it will ask so).
4. Reboot and use your new password.

Comment: It is asking me to login first